# How to print values of character class in R?

Tags: arrays, r, class, printing, character

I have a file(attached) from which I'm getting employee's attendance and want to check whether there is a "November 9" in it or not?

```
setwd("F://Uni////DataScience")
mydata<-file("Emp_A.txt", open="r")
line<-readLines(mydata)
print(line)
class(line)
newTxt <- unlist(strsplit(line, split = ", "))
print(newTxt)
x=0
while(x<=length(newTxt)){
if(newTxt="November 9")
   print("*****")
   x=x+1
}
# .txt file format is:
Sunday, November 1, 2015
--
--
Monday, November 2, 2015
10:21:27
17:58:12
Tuesday, November 3, 2015
10:13:09
18:52:44
Wednesday, November 4, 2015
10:11:52
18:40:36
Thursday, November 5, 2015
10:31:42
18:16:57
Friday, November 6, 2015
10:13:13
--
Saturday, November 7, 2015
--
--
Sunday, November 8, 2015
--
--
# and so on..
```

so at first, I get lines from file, then split it with ", " so I may have separated "November_space_dates".
And then I want to put check on it.

Comment: `any(grepl("November 9", readLines("Emp_A.txt"), fixed = TRUE))` should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal here to check whether or not "November 9" is in the file, then you can write a simple function that does just that with the following:

```
is_nov9_in <- function(file_name) {
  file_conn <- file(file_name, open = 'r')
  line_items <- readLines(file_conn)
  close(file_conn)
  ifelse(sum(grepl('November 9', line_items, ignore.case = TRUE)) > 0, TRUE, FALSE)
}

is_nov9_in(file_name = 'Emp_A.txt')
[1] FALSE
```

Here the function checks if "November 9" is in the file "Emp_A.txt". Since "November 9" is not in the file, then the function returns `FALSE`.

But if you are looking for a general purpose function that checks whether or not a given date is in the file, then you may write a more general function mimicking the following:

```
is_month_day_in <- function(file_name, month = 'November', day = 9) {
  file_conn <- file(file_name, open = 'r')
  line_items <- readLines(file_conn)
  close(file_conn)
  DAY <- paste(month, day, sep = ' ')
  ifelse(sum(grepl(DAY, line_items, ignore.case = TRUE)) > 0, TRUE, FALSE)
}

is_month_day_in(file_name = 'Emp_A.txt', month = 'November', day = 7)
[1] TRUE
```

Here the function is more general; so you can feed it a `month` and `day` and it looks for that combination of `month` and `day` in the file. By default, this general function searches for "November 9" if you only feed it the `file_name`. For example, `is_month_day_in('Emp_A.txt')` should return `FALSE`, because it is *by default* looking for "November 9". But when you provide the exact `month` and `day` you want, then the result will vary depending on whether or not that combination of `month` and `day` is in the file. For instance, since "November 7" is in the file then the `is_month_day_in(file_name = 'Emp_A.txt', month = 'November', day = 7)` returns `TRUE`.

I hope this helps.